# How to build a big data platform to receive and store big data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, data-warehouse, platform

I am trying to build up a big data platform to receive and store in Hadoop  large amount of heterogeneous data like (documents,videos,images,sensors data, etc) then implement classification process.
 So what architecture can help me as I’m currently using
**VMware VSphere EXSi
Hadoop

Habse
Thrift
XAMPP**
All these working fine  but I don’t know how to receive a large amount of data and how to store the data because I discovered that Hbase is a column-oriented data base and it’s not data warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize solution for type of Big Data ( Structured, Semi-Structured and Un-Structured)

You can use **HIVE/HBASE** for structured data if total data size <= 10 TB

You can use **SQOOP** to import structured data from traditional RDBMS database Oracle, SQL Server etc.

You can use **FLUME** for processing Un-structured data.

You can use Content Management System to process Un-structured data & Semi-Structured data - Tera Or Peta bytes of data. If you are storing un-structured data, I prefer to store the data in CMS and use meta data information in NoSQL database like HBASE

To process Big data streaming, you can use **PIG**.

Have a look at [Structured Data](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/structured-data-storage-and-processing-in-hadoop.html) and [Un-Structured data](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/unstructured-data-in-a-big-data-environment.html) handling in Hadoop

[image: Different type of data solutions]